# Use updated data for an email in a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, field-update

I link the entry source DE to the contact record under an attribute group and then I can use a Decision split with Contact Data.

I'm using this DE for a welcome journey. First I check if the Journey Data.FirstName is empty or not. If not, I send an email asking him to update his profile. 3 days later y check in Contact Data if Account_Salesforce.FirstName is filled or not. If he has his First Name filled he will receive an email saying "Hi **John**, thanks for updating your profile."

My problem is that when John entered in the Journey, the FirstName field was empty in the journey Data and Contact Data. Then, When I'm sending the email knowing that he has the FistName filled (due to the decision split),  the FirstName is not appearing in the email, and I think that this happens because the data is static one the journey is activated.

Any help? I should create a new Journey for those that update the name?

Regards.

Comment: You would need to use ampscript to do a lookup as opposed to personalization strings

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You mean that the only solution is to use ampscript in the email code and instead of using FirstName from the entry source DE  I should use FirstName from Account_Salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in this help doc:
[Personalization in the Journey Builder Email Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_personalization_in_the_journey_builder_send_email_activity.htm&type=5)

> Journey data differs from contact data because it preserves the state of a contact's data at the moment an entry event fires. The journey uses that initial data throughout a journey.

> If you are more experienced, use AMPScript for personalization. Use the `%%=Lookup()=%%` function to personalize an email with data not found in journey data, or contact data that has changed since the journey started.

You would need to lookup either back to the entry source or to the sync object to pull this value